# How to pass float3x3 to HLSL Shader in DirectX?

Tags: matrix, directx, hlsl

I'm having trouble with passing 3x3 matrix through a constant buffer to my shader in DirectX. This is how I define my constant buffer:

In .cpp:

```
struct PostProcessConvolutionCB {
    float screenWidth;
    float screenHeight;
    float sum;
    XMFLOAT3X3 kernel;
};
```

In .hlsl:

```
struct PostProcessConvolutionCB {
    float screenWidth;
    float screenHeight;
    float sum;
    float3x3 kernel;
};
ConstantBuffer<PostProcessConvolutionCB> cb : register(b0);

struct PixelShaderInput {
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput IN) : SV_Target {
    return float4(cb.kernel[1][1], 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
}
```

It seems like access to some element is all messed up. To test this I initialized the matrix in the constant buffer like this: `XMFLOAT3X3(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f);` and tried displaying the value of each element by hardcoding the matrix indices in the shader like in hlsl snippet above (`cb.kernel[1][1]`). After 9 runs I got the following results:

```
kernel[0][0] = 0.1
kernel[1][0] = 0.2
kernel[2][0] = 0.3

kernel[0][1] = 0.5
kernel[1][1] = 0.6
kernel[2][1] = 0.7

kernel[0][2] = 0.9
kernel[1][2] = 1.0
kernel[2][2] = 1.0
```

Seems like every row is aligned to 4 floats. Changing the matrix to 4x4 helps but I guess there has to be a way to use float3x3 type.

How to handle this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are hitting is that the HLSL rules for packing are different than C++. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-packing-rules):

> HLSL packing rules are similar to performing a `#pragma pack 4` with Visual Studio, which packs data into 4-byte boundaries. Additionally, HLSL packs data so that it does not cross a 16-byte boundary.

Also keep in mind that by default, HLSL uses 'column-major' matrices while DirectXMath uses 'row-major'. This is why you see lots of samples that transpose the matrix going from `XMFLOAT?X?` to an HLSL constant buffer struct. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-optimizing#using-directxmath-with-direct3d).

Generally your best option is to use `XMFLOAT4X4` for HLSL matrices. One option for saving a little constant buffer memory (useful for skinning in particular where you have many bones that do not include projection transformations) is to use in HLSL:

```
struct SkinnedEffectConstants
{
…
    XMVECTOR bones[MaxBones][3];
};
```

Then in C++ you use:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    XMMATRIX boneMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x3(…));

    boneConstant[i][0] = boneMatrix.r[0];
    boneConstant[i][1] = boneMatrix.r[1];
    boneConstant[i][2] = boneMatrix.r[2];
}
```

Comment: Yup, that makes perfect sense. I went with the float4x3 approach  and it works. Thank you!